# How to move the create account checkbox on Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

On my current checkout page I have the "create account" checkbox after the email field. What I am attempting to do is to move the create account checkbox inline and next to the email field. So I would have the email field on the left and the created account checkbox to the right.

I am able to move the create account checkbox but I just cannot figure out how to achieve the look I described. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Checkout page here :
https://www.dailymutt.com/checkout/

[image: This is the look I would like to achieve after making the edits to move the field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done adding a new similar checkbox field to billing form and hiding the real checkbox one with CSS. Then with the help of jQuery, you can trigger the hidden checkbox from the duplicated one.

Here is that code:

```php
// CSS rules
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'move_checkout_create_an_account_css' );
function move_checkout_create_an_account_css() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) :
    ?><style>
        .woocommerce-account-fields label.woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox {display: none !important;}
        #account_cb_field {margin-top: 32px;}
        #account_cb_field input {margin-right: 6px;}
    </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Add a checkbox to billing section
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'move_checkout_create_an_account_checkbox' );
function move_checkout_create_an_account_checkbox( $fields ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Make email field on half on left side
        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first');

        // Custom checkbox on half right side
        $fields['billing']['account_cb'] = array(
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __("Create an account?", "woocommerce"),
            'class' => array('form-row-last'),
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}

// remove "(optional)" from the new checkbox
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && $key === 'account_cb' ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// The jQuery code
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'move_checkout_create_an_account_js' );
function move_checkout_create_an_account_js() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?><script>
    (function($){
        $('input[name=account_cb]').on( 'click', function() {
            $('input[name=createaccount]').trigger('click');
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: TheAztec - Thank you so much! This worked perfect! You rock!